# Why does the from ... import ... statement contain an implicit import?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, python-packaging

Given a package:

```sh
package/
├── __init__.py
└── module.py
```

**__init__.py:**

```py
from .module import function
```

**module.py:**

```py
def function():
    pass
```

One can import the package and print its namespace.

```sh
python -c 'import package; print(dir(package))'
```

```py
['__builtins__', ..., 'function', 'module']
```

**Question:**

Why does the namespace of `package` contain `module` when only `function` was imported in the `__init__.py`?

I would have expected that the `package`'s namespace would only contain `function` and not `module`. This mechanism is also mentioned in the [Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#submodules),

> "When a submodule is loaded using any mechanism (e.g. importlib APIs,
>   the import or import-from statements, or built-in `__import__()`) a
>   binding is placed in the parent module’s namespace to the submodule
>   object."

but is not really motivated. For me this choice seems odd, as I think of sub-modules as implementation detail to structure packages and do not expect them to be part of the API as the structure can change.

Also I know "Python is for consenting adults" and one cannot truly hide anything from a user. But I would argue, that binding the sub-modules names to the package's scopes makes it less obvious to a user what is actually part of the API and what can change.

Why no use a `__sub_modules__` attribute or so to make sub-modules accessible to a user? What is the reason for this design decision?

Comment: You say you think of submodules as implementation details. This is not the design intent behind submodules; they can be, and extremely commonly are, part of the public interface of a package. Look at `collections`, `numpy`, `requests`, `tensorflow`, `urllib`, `asyncio`, etc.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica I am aware of that. But the same can be achieved by importing submodules **explicitly**. For example numpy.linalg: `from . import linalg`. I just find it odd that `from .linalg import dot` would bind `linalg` to the `numpy` scope. So I don't think submodules shouldn't be part of the interface in general, but I think it should not happen implicitly.

Comment: "but is not really motivated". It literally explains your situation completely, but if you are looking for the reasoning, you'll have to browse the mailing list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You say you think of submodules as implementation details. This is not the design intent behind submodules; they can be, and extremely commonly are, part of the public interface of a package. The import system was designed to facilitate access to submodules, not to prevent access.

Loading a submodule places a binding into the parent's namespace because this is necessary for access to the module. For example, after the following code:

```
import package.submodule
```

the expression `package.submodule` must evaluate to the module object for the submodule. `package` evaluates to the module object for the package, so this module object must have a `submodule` attribute referring to the module object for the submodule.

At this point, you are almost certainly thinking, "hey, there's no reason `from .submodule import function` has to do the same thing!" It does the same thing because this attribute binding is part of submodule initialization, which only happens on the first import, and which needs to do the same setup regardless of what kind of import triggered it.

This is not an extremely strong reason. With enough changes and rejiggering, the import system definitely *could* have been designed the way you expect. It was not designed that way because the designers had different priorities than you. Python's design cares very little about hiding things or supporting any notion of privacy.

Answer (score 1):

you have to understand that Python is a runtime language. `def`, `class` and `import` are all executable statements, that will, when executed, create (respectively) a `function`, `class` or `module` object and bind them in the current namespace.

wrt/ modules (packages being modules too - at least at runtime), the very first time a module is imported (directly or indirectly) for a given process, the matching .py (well, usually it's compiled .pyc version) is executed (all statements at the top level are executed in order), and the resulting namespace will be used to populate the `module` instance. Only once this has been done can any name defined in the module be accessed (you cannot access something that doesn't exist yet, can you ?). Then the module object is cached in `sys.modules` for subsequent imports. In this process, a when a sub-module is loaded, it's considered as an attribute of it's parent module.

> For me this choice seems odd, as I think of sub-modules as implementation detail to structure packages and do not expect them to be part of the API as the structure can change

Actually, Python's designers considered things the other way round: a "package" (note that there's no 'package' type at runtime) is mostly a convenience to organize a collection of related modules - IOW, the ̀module`is the real building block - and as a matter of fact, at runtime, when what you import is technically a "package", it still materializes as a`module` object.

Now wrt/ the "do not expect them to be part of the API as the structure can change", this has of course been taken into account. It's actually a quite common pattern to start out with a single module, and then turn it into a package as the code base grows - without impacting client code, of course. The key here is to make proper use of your package's initializer - the `__init__.py` file - which is actually what your package's `module` instance is built from. This lets the package act as a "facade", masking the "implementation details" of which submodule effectively defines which function, class or whatever.

So the solution here is plain simply to, in your package's `__init__.py`, 1/ import the names you want to make public (so the client code can import directly from your package instead of having to go thru the submodule) and 2/ define the `__all__` attributes with the names that should be considered public so the interface is clearly documented.

FWIW, this last operation should be done for all your submodules too, and you can also use the _single_leading_underscore naming convention for things that are really really "implementation details".

None of this will of course prevent anyone to import even "private" names directly from your submodules, but then they are on their own when something breaks ("we are all consenting adults" etc).